# Using InLineAssignHelper in a ForEach to update two fields

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following code

```
de.Tbl_Summary.Where(Function(c) CBool(c.CPID = uPn AndAlso _
c.C_Year = cutoffDates.ActualClaimYear AndAlso _
c.C_Month >= cutoffDates.ActualClaimMonth _
)).ToList().ForEach(Function(r) InlineAssignHelper(r.TeamID, uTid))
```

which was converted and adapted from a C# example. This works fine but I now need to update two fields so I tried...

```
 de.Tbl_Summary.Where(Function(c) CBool(c.CPID = uPn AndAlso _
 c.C_Year = cutoffDates.ActualClaimYear AndAlso _
 c.C_Month >= cutoffDates.ActualClaimMonth _
 )).ToList().ForEach(Function(r) InlineAssignHelper(r.TeamID, uTid), _
 InlineAssignHelper(r.CostCentre, uCostCentre))
```

This does not work as I get a wavy line under the second InLineAssignHelper with the error

```
Error   BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Sub 
ForEach(action As Action(Of Tbl_IndividualClaims))'.
```

How can I implement a ForEach that will update 2 fields in TblIndividualClaims?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is the VB converted code for InlineAssignHelper (converted from C#)

```
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely MUST keep it the same format, then it will end up like so:

```
.ForEach(Function(r) 
             InlineAssignHelper(r.TeamID, uTid)
             InlineAssignHelper(r.CostCentre, uCostCentre)
         End Function)
```

P.S. It makes more sense to use a `Sub` in this case

Comment: This give the error Cannot infer a return type consider adding an 'As' clause to specify return type

Comment: Exactly.. Use a `Sub`. You aren't returning anything

Comment: I've updated my question and added the InlineAssignHelper code which shows that the Function is returning something.

Comment: Currently I have the code working but... I'm doing a select to list and then a ForEach updating the TeamID and then doing the same select and another ForEach updating the CostCentre... this must be an overkill...

Comment: I have tried ForEach(Sub(r)... but get the same error Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Sub 
ForEach(action As Action(Of Tbl_IndividualClaims))'.

Comment: Using a comma to separate the lines?